# RabbitMQ Listener stopping automatically

Tags: java, rabbitmq, shutdown, spring-amqp

I am using spring rabbit mq template based listener

Under increased load, the listener simply shuts down

How to prevent the listener from shutting down?

Or how to restart the listener immediately after shutdown?

I am using following config:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" password="guest" port="5672" username="guest" />

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                 exchange="${amqp_exchange_name}"/>

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

<rabbit:queue name="${amqp_queue_name}"/>

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" concurrency="5">
    <rabbit:listener ref="joblistener" queue-names="${amqp_queue_name}"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>

<bean id="joblistener" class="com.org.sample.Consumer"/>
```

Consumer is my listener with following function in it

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
      //do something
}
```

Comment: What happens when more than 5 messages are received when the 1st message is being processed?  .. considering concurrency="5"?

Comment: What version of spring-rabbit? When you say it "just shuts down", is there anything in the log?

Comment: I am getting Following messages: SEVERE: Consumer thread error, thread abort. INFO: Stopping container from aborted consumer. Apr 21, 2014 12:26:21 PM org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer doShutdown

Comment: What version of `amqp-client` and `spring-rabbitmq` are you using?